# copy paste and cut text from host to guest in vmware workstation 15 player

Tags: vmware, vmware-workstation

I googled before and found that by turning on the "**Enable copy and paste**" under Guest Isolation, I can copy/cut/paste text from guest to host and vice versa. But I don't see "**Guest Isolation**" after clicking on Player->Manage->virtual machine settings->option. I have tried to install the VMware tools and I seem to have successfully installed it, but still no use. Is this feature only available in VMware pro?

Comment: VMware Player has no such options (at least not in the GUI). Copy and paste are always enabled.

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu (Guest OS), you need to install `open-vm-tools` and `open-vm-tools-desktop`.

```
sudo apt install open-vm-tools open-vm-tools-desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Some versions of vmware-tools are buggy (copy&paste does not work). Try an older version (they can be downloaded for free from vmware.com).

Note that newer Linux distributions already include the vmware-tools. They may not be installed by default (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56640569/822870)).